# create-react-app running on Smart TV browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, create-react-app, television

I am facing a big problem with `create-react-app` environment on trying to run my application inside a Smart TV browser.

**Specification TV and browser (http://whatismybrowser.com)**

- TV: Panasonic TC-32DS600B
- Browser: Chrome 23 FreeBSD
- userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11;FreeBSD;U;Viera:pt-BR) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Viera/3.18.1 Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11

Here is what I am trying to:

1. create a fresh `create-react-app` project
2. run `yarn build`
3. `yarn global add serve && serve -s build`
4. Use my LAN IP (not localhost) and type on url address browser `http://<my-lan-ip>:5000` (5000 port as default port provided by `serve` command)

When I follow these steps I get a blank page. The blank page only occours in a TV browser. On PC and Mobile runs fine.

So I am wondering and ask here to have some share thoughts:

1. Old TV browsers doesn't support React?
2. Or maybe is just a polyfill problem?
3. Or it doesn't support HTML5, CSS3?

Anyone have already face this problem? Any solution or No, it is not possible?

**EDITED: Solution**

Thanks to @Rikin and @JoeClay I came up with a solution. First, after download the Chrome version 23, I could see the problem is polyfills (Set and Map).

So after install `yarn add core-js --dev` and `yarn add raf --dev`.

Update *src/index.js*

```
import 'core-js/es6/map'; // <-- added this line after installed packages
import 'core-js/es6/set'; // <-- added this line after installed packages
import 'raf/polyfill'; // <-- added this line after installed packages

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Also, the portion of [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/javascript-environment-requirements.html) which helped to find this solution.

Comment: It might be helpful to know which make/model of TV you're trying to run it on.

Comment: @JoeClay updated. I have forgot to provided these infos.

Comment: Probably download older desired Chrome version: http://www.oldapps.com/google_chrome.php and work on that in local and see if its successful. Remember its not React running in browser rather JS running in the browser.

Comment: @Rikin yes, you are right. JS running in the browser :)

Comment: Thanks, man, saved my day!

Comment: so you completed with react js? or html5, css3? which one is the best to support the following TVs: Samsung Tizen, LG WebOS, Hisense TV app & PS4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newer versions of React (v16+) require:

- The `Map` and `Set` data structures
- The `window.requestAnimationFrame()` API

According to MDN, basic [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) support weren't added to Chrome until version 38, and you had to use a vendor prefix to access [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) until Chrome 24.

Since your TV uses Chrome 23, you'll need to polyfill those APIs. The [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/javascript-environment-requirements.html) suggest using [`core-js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) or  [`babel-polyfill`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) for this purpose.

Comment: If I install core-js package I have to eject the create-react-app application?

Comment: @marquesm91: Not as far as I know! It should literally be as simple as doing `npm install core-js --save` and then following the example from the docs page I linked. Same deal with the RAF polyfill.

Comment: I follow the docs and add in `index.js` the first two lines `import 'core-js/es6/map'` and `import 'core-js/es6/set'` and even further I added `import 'raf/polyfill'`. Plus, I run `yarn add core-js --dev` and `yarn add raf --dev`. I have generated the build ant yet still gets the same results: blank screen on TV :(

Comment: Agh - then Rikin's suggestion of downloading Chrome 23 to your PC might be a decent one, unless you can figure out how to access the developer tools/Chrome remote debugging on your TV.

Comment: I have search a way to see a developer tools remote on TV but haven't find any solution. I will follow Rikin's suggestion and later come up with a feedback

Comment: Well, even if this answer doesn't end up being the solution, I wish you luck figuring out the issue :)

Comment: I got it Joe, thank you so much. I will update the answer with the solution

Comment: I tried this. It started working but my UI is not looking as expected. The same UI looks good on my laptop. Any suggestions? @marquesm91

Comment: @YadyneshDesai I solved this CSS problem using `styled-components` because it resolves old css prefix for you. You could give it a try!

Comment: @marquesm91 I have already created the css for this using bootstrap. Do I have to change everything?

Answer (score 1):

If your desired aim is to have your app run *just* on a smart TV perhaps give `react-tv` a look: https://github.com/raphamorim/react-tv

Comment: Even if I want to, `react-tv` isn't a accepted solution because only supports LG's television. So will not attend me :(